# Unexpected behavior: np.abs()/ abs not working working on lists/ numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

suppose we have a numpy array

```
[1 -2 -5 -7 -6 5 8] # keep mind the number of elements are close to million here
```

each element will be converted to a binary array and the length of that array will be ->

```
length of (binary maximum integer value) + 1 # in our case it is 8 ('1000')
                                                # len('1000') + 1 which is 5
   # len + 1 is to give a space to add the value for positive or negative flag i.e. 0 or 5
```

it'll be like..

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1], # 1
 [5, 0, 0, 1, 0], # -2
 ..]
```

so,  to find the highest numeric value I do

```
max_num = len(np.binary_repr(max(np.abs(music))) + 1 # music is the array
```

this give me a value `32767`.

the problem is that `32767` is not the highest value in the array, it is `32768` and the method is not detecting it. why?

and to convert the numbers to binary array ->

```
for _ in music:

    print(np.abs(_), _, i, len(music))

    mate = list('{0:b}'.format(np.abs(_)).zfill(max_num))

    dat = list(map(int, mate))

    if _ < 0:
        fl = 5
    else:
        fl = 0

    muse.append(dat)

    muse[i][0] = fl

    i = i + 1
```

**EDIT 1**

So, I've been digging again to this problem again. and i changed everything to simplicity, I replaced one liner statement with a simple `for` loop.

the thing is, `np.abs()` is not CONVERTING `-32768` to positive, this is a really obnoxious behavior here are the screen shots.
[image]

**HERE** you can see, four terms, the first one is `np.abs(number)` of the array, second is the simple number, third is the index of it, and fourth is the total number of elements in the array.

**EDIT 2**

okay so another weird thing.

so as i mentioned earlier that i'm now using simple `for` loop for finding the maximum number, but `np.abs()` was not identifying it.

i now used `* - 1` to convert it to positive number, and it works now.. check this out.
[image]
so what is this??

Comment: doublechecked max in many ways - it seems working fine with np. there should be some other problem here; don't have time to dig more for now.

Comment: I've read this question many times carefully but still cannot get the point. What are you talking about? It seems to be a simple convertion, so could you also provide a simple explaination instead of such a huge essay.

Comment: I have provided an easy explanation

Comment: All I can tell you is that `max(list(map(abs, list(music)))))` can be replaced by the much more performant `np.abs(music).max()`. I don't understand the question either, please provide a [minimal, complete and verificable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including your desired and actual output

Comment: guys thank you for support, but check out the edit it's totally weird

Comment: okay so now i focused on the finding the maximum element part. i hope this helps

Comment: guys check our edit 2, what is really going on ?? I've never experienced anything like this

Comment: people check out my answer to my question what do you think??

Answer (score 1):

I've got to a terminal.  I was wrong abs(-32768) int16 returns -32768.

The easiest way to proceed may well be to convert the 'music' array to int32.

An alternative may be to use uint16

```
import numpy as np
abs(arr).astype(np.uint16).max()
```

will return 32768 if there is a -32768 in arr.

```
Signed 16 bit  -32768 = bin: 1000 0000 0000 0000
Unsigned 16 bit 32768 = bin: 1000 0000 0000 0000
```

If I understand your further processing this may help.

```
a=np.arange(-128*256, 128*256, dtype=np.int16) # All possible int16s
b=abs(a).astype(np.uint16)

In [29]: b.max()
Out[29]: 32768

In [26]: a
Out[26]: array([-32768, -32767, -32766, ...,  32765,  32766,  32767], dtype=int16)

In [27]: b
Out[27]: array([32768, 32767, 32766, ..., 32765, 32766, 32767], dtype=uint16)

In [28]: a<0
Out[28]: array([ True,  True,  True, ..., False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Or even

```
In [31]: 5*(a<0).astype(np.int16)
Out[31]: array([5, 5, 5, ..., 0, 0, 0], dtype=int16)
```

Comment: So like it just won't work for `abs` or `np.abs` but certainly work for   *  -1

Comment: It's not possible to hold 32768 in an int16.  It's not the conversion method. If you have the space to convert 'music' to int32 everything should work as you originally expected.